# Is there an operator to measure pre-SSB boson states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, gauge-invariance, electroweak

A common statement is that post-SSB electroweak gauge bosons are linear combinations of pre-SSB gauge bosons.

It is also usually stated that pre-SSB bosons can also be thought of as linear combinations of post-SSB bosons - it's just a choice of basis, after all.

However, with a choice of basis, there usually comes an operator corresponding to an observable which allows us to measure the eigenstates corresponding to the chosen basis .
The eigenvectors of such operator will correspond to the basis states.

If there was a quantum operator / observable whose eigenvectors correpond to the 'pure' pre-SSB boson states (B, W1, W2, W3), we would be able to 'detect' pre-SSB bosons in post-SSB environment - i.e. measure whether the photon 'chooses' to be a 'B' or a 'W' at any given interaction.

So: does such an operator / observable exist? Can it be constructed? Or does it even make sense?

**Edit**

I'm thinking in terms of the following analogy:

1. A photon is usually emitted in a superposition of spin left / spin right states. Upon 'arrival' however we can always measure it to be either one or the other.
2. A photon is emitted in superposition of B / W states. Upon 'arrival' we should somehow be able to measure if it is one or the other.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/739678/have-the-w-0-w-1-w-2-and-b-bosons-of-electroweak-fame-ever-been-discov).

Answer (score 0):

It's linear algebra. In terms of the mass eigenstates, $\gamma  , 
Z^0$,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 B^0 \\
 W^3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta_\text{W} & -\sin \theta_\text{W} \\
\sin \theta_\text{W} & \cos \theta_\text{W} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 \gamma \\
 Z^0 \end{pmatrix} , $$
so the operators destroying the corresponding states, usable in projectors, are
$$
B^0= \cos\theta_W ~~  \gamma  -\sin\theta_W ~~ Z^0, \\
W^3= \cos\theta_W ~~ Z^0  +\sin\theta_W ~~\gamma,
$$
but I am not sure what you expect to learn from them.

So the photon is 0.22 *B* and 0.78 *W*, if you could measure that.

Comment: Yes, these are exactly the eigenstates I am talking about. I'm wondering if there theoretically exists a physical observable to measure them.

Comment: Perhaps in an early universe simulation comparing multiplicities. But in each energy regime, one of the two bases are promising to be dysfunctional/meaningless...

Comment: Perhaps, but I feel the observable should still exist. Could you elaborate on 'comparing multiplicities' a bit, please?